# callback function returning value passes type check as void function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types

I am currently learning TypeScript, and my understanding is that specifying a type for any variable/function should prompt TypeScript to enforce a type-check on its computed value, with the exception of type `any`.

However, I was surprised today to find that when I created a function with a **parameter** of type `() => void`, and the function passed into that function does return something, there was no error from TypeScript. Why is this?

```
function doSomething(callback: () => void) : void {
  callback();
  // callback is of type `void`, so shouldn't this cause an error?
}
 
doSomething(() => 1); // will return 1 when invoked
```

Interestingly, when I try to store and use the returned value, I do get an error from TypeScript:

```
function doSomething(callback: () => void) : void {
  let a = callback();
  console.log(a + 1); //  Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'void' and 'number'.
}
 
doSomething(() => 1);
```

From this example, it appears `a` is still stored as type `void` even though the `callback` function should be returning `1`. What's happening under the hood here?